# MDX query to filter dimension on metric values

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I want to filter out dimensions if the metric values not exist over that dimension, but I have some metric containing some raw data ie, Infinity, 1.#NN. 
I am using `NON EMPTY()` but it is not filtering data correctly as it filter the dimension if all metrics are null but in my case it fetch 'Infinity' dimensions too:

Mdx Query:

```
SELECT
{ 
 [Measures].[1],
 [Measures].[2],
 [Measures].[3]
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS

, NON EMPTY Hierarchize (
 {
  DrilldownLevel ( { [Roles].[Dimension].[All] } )
 }
) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
, [Roles].[Roster Role].[Roster Role].[Roster Role - Enterprise]
, [Roles].[Roster Role].[Roster Role].[Roster Role - Group] ON ROWS
FROM [Cuve]
WHERE ( [Dates].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2013], [Markets].[Market].&[1], [Areas].  [Area].&[8], [Roles].[Enterprise Role].&[2] )
```

I can not `NONEMPTY()` as it remove dimension if any of metric is null while I want to remove if all are null.

I want that I can filter out dimension, ie if metric value is not an integer (eg, "Infinity" or other data) or filter it out by `NOT IN()` kind of function.

Thanks

Comment: The equivalent of not in is basically to use Except

Answer (score 2):

First, it sounds like you are dividing by 0 in the calculations for your measures.  If you can, I would rewrite them to return null where the denominator is 0. 
This would look something like:

```
IIF([Measures].[denominator] = 0, Null, [Measures].[Numerator/[Measures].[Denominator])
```

Then you can use Filter. I'm not quite sure I know enough about your cube's structure to write your query, but try something like this:

```
Select {
[Measures].[1], 
[Measures].[2], 
[Measures].3]} on COLUMNS, 
{ Filter([Roles].[Dimension].[Dimension].members, CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[1],[Measures].[2],[Measures].[3], 0) <> 0)
* ({[Roles].[Roster Role].[Roster Role].[Roster Role - Enterprise], [Roles].[Roster Role].[Roster Role].[Roster Role - Group]})} on ROWS
FROM [Cuve]
WHERE ( [Dates].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2013], [Markets].[Market].&[1], [Areas].  [Area].&[8], [Roles].[Enterprise Role].&[2] )
```